# Connecting to windows 7, mount.cifs error(115)

Tags: wireless, mount, windows-7, password, cifs

I'm trying to share a "Share" folder located in my Ubuntu 14.04LTS desktop with my Windows 7 computer through my local wireless using:

```
sudo mount.cifs //WindowsPCname/Users /home/UserName_Ubuntu/Desktop/Share/ -o user=UserName_W7
```

After it asks me for the UserName_Ubuntu password, it asks me for another password (which I guess is UserName_W7's password). It then gives me a "mount error(115): Operation now in progress", the meaning of which I have no idea (and the sharing is not accomplished).

Furthermore, I don't understand why mount.cifs always asks me for the password (the second one after sudo), even if I have configured the sharing settings in W7 not to ask for password (and confirmed that the settings work from another Windows computer).

What should I do now?